# WPAutoP doesn't seem to be working

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wysiwyg

I have a blog that has WP-Ecommerce setup. The problem I am having is with the WYSIWYG editor. If I paste text into the editor it encloses paragraphs in div tags rather than P tags. Now if it is an E-commerce part of the blog ie. the new product WYSIWYG editor it always does this never encloses with p tags. This is breaking the page formatting.

I have not edited any of the core WP files and my functions.php does not disable the WPAutoP filter. Could someone help me ensure the p tags are always used over the div tags?

Comment: Have you tried switching to the HTML editor and see if you have `div` tags there? If there are no block-level HTML tags, then it is an issue with formatting. I'd suggest stopping any plugins and seeing if that would make a difference. If there are `div` tags around your text, then again it could be a problem with a plugin, or because you've copy/pasted some text from somewhere and you got the div's carried over to the tinyMCE.

Comment: only plugin is WP-Ecommerce... The problem is the same in the HTML editor... It formats with divs there also....

Comment: Can you get rid of the div tags in the HTML editor, save and see what happens? If you have div tags again, then that's a really strange issue.

Comment: deleting the div tags manually on the HTML editor solves the problem, its a clients website though so need it to stop doing it any suggestions :)

Comment: Well the problem here is that they've copied some text and pasted it into the visual editor and the `div` tags got carried over. You can try with a search/replace(if it's just `<div></div>` - as in no classes, etc, but that might also strip the closing tags of div elements that have a class and that would be a mess), but that might not always work. How much content do you have? If it's not too much to go over and manually fix it and then just instruct the client to either paste in HTML view, or use the "Paste as plain Text" button that might work.